# wrong rendering of star rating jquery star rating widget and split stars

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

i'm using the jquery star widget in our next project, it worked fine for other projects in the past, now it works, but the client has requested specific for these 2 facts:

1) the widget needs 5 stars, split in half  as seen on the api 2 page on the website (http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/#main-menu=2)

2) they want the big star design as seen in demo's on tab 6  (http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/#main-menu=3&demo-tabs=5)

now, upon combining the 2, (big star css, and half star option ({split:2})
the lahout is garbled... it seems like the plugin is giving an 8px width to the elements
with jquery, why is this not handled in the css? and how can i solve it without changing the plugin itself (to keep it safe when future updates are done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i fixed this myself,

i have overwritten the default css so it fits our own design.

had to make the space for stars bigger, from 8 to 16px.