# Star Rating Widget problem with split stars

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to implement the Star Rating Widget with 5 stars split in half, but all I'm getting is 2 and a half stars where there should be 5.

[image: 2 stars and a half]

I'm following the demo on the official site: http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/index.html#main-menu=2&demo-tabs=4

As explained there, all I've done is

> $(this).stars({ split: 2 });

If I set split: 1 everything works ok. I guess there's a problem with the width, but my css/js skills are really low.

I've found a similar question ( [wrong rendering of star rating jquery star rating widget and split stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459358/wrong-rendering-of-star-rating-jquery-star-rating-widget-and-split-stars) ) but it doesn't help me that much.

Thanks!

Edit: link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu9pM/1/ It doesn't load the star, I hope it serves you anyway

Edit: update with a general view of the output along with the HTML and CSS
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to show HTML and CSS as the final output? You can use Firebug to help you

Comment: I'm not too sure of what a "fiddle" is, but I've updated the question so that you can see the final output, the HTML and the CSS of a star. All those <br> and <div> tags are created by the Star Rating widget, originally I create radio buttons

Comment: this is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net
add your code to the appropriate sections and share the link here.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you highlight the #ratings div and <td> and show the CSS for those.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to a fiddle

Comment: In Firebug, can you click on the body tag and then click 'Edit' and copy all the HTML and update the fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is absolutely correct behaviour! 
If you have originally 5 radio buttons, and you split them by 2, then you'll have 2,5 stars, because each radio button is represented by a star/2.

You should start with 10 radio buttons to end up with 5 stars split in half.

In other words, no matter how much you split the stars, each piece will always represent ONE input (ie. radio button)

All the best.
The author :)

Comment: works perfect, I must have misread the documentation. Btw, thanks for the plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

Without further seeing  your HTML code and full CSS, try setting the width like so:

```
td, #ratings { 
   width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That increases the width of the cells but the stars remain unchanged. Now all cells look like the ones under "Septiembre", with a blank gap between the stars and the next cell.